# Current flow between two points

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I can measure a voltage that is induced on my skin from a 50hz electromagnetic field (emf) source using a multimeter, how can I measure the induced current flowing between my finger and ground when I touch a grounded wire whilst in the same electromagnetic field.

I have tried using an ammeter to measure the current under the impression that the positive terminal would serve as a ground. However I cannot get a positive reading whilst doing this.
My understanding is that current flows from high to low potentials. Why is it that no current registers on the multimeter?

Following ohms law I would expect to see the 1v measured on my skin, which in this model has a resistance of 10,000 ohms, translate to a current of 0.1 milliamp however the multimeter/ammeter doesnt register this. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

You have most likely been measuring a voltage that was induced in the loop formed by the multimeter leads and your skin. Do the measurement again, this time just shorting the leads while forming a loop of similar area. If the voltage is still there, it has nothing to do with your skin.

If you wanted to measure the electrostatic current from your body acting as a capacitive antenna to ground, you would need an electrometer with much higher impedance. Your body capacitance is on the order of 100pF. The $10k\Omega$ internal resistance of your instrument forms a highpass with a frequency of 160kHz with that capacitance. An AC voltage with a frequency of 50Hz will be suppressed by a factor of 3000 by that highpass. Another way of looking at it is that you are actually doing a current measurement with your voltmeter, rather than a voltage measurement.

So what's the AC current flowing trough your body? If the voltage is 230V (the current line voltage in Europe, I believe), then there will be $230V*2\pi*100pF*50Hz=7.2uA$ of current flowing in the best case, which is probably below the sensitivity of your instrument. The good news is that you can easily build your own electrometer amplifier with not much more than a couple batteries and a CMOS opamp these days.

This is a nice circuit that anybody can build with reasonable success: http://amasci.com/electrom/sas51p1.html#Electro. For your purposes you can bypass the filter circuit around the fourth opamp and if all you want is to detect the 50Hz capacitively coupled AC signal, then you won't need OP 2 and 3, either. The simple circuit around OP1 is enough. You can use two 9V batteries as power supply. Put the circuit in a metal box (a food can is perfect!) and make sure that everything is kitchen clean, because modern Opamps can detect sub-pA (some can do fA!) of current and getting an electrometer to behave nicely depends on absolutely cleanliness around the input leads. Even small amounts of solder residue and other organic matter that attracts moisture will short circuit the small currents that you are trying to measure and the circuit will do strange things like drift to one of the rails and do wild voltage swings on its own. On the upside, if you master the design of electrometer amplifiers and you understand what you are doing, then you have learned one of the basic skills of an experimental physicist/EE.

Comment: The voltage is only there when I touch the positive probe, and is not dependent on the configuration of the probe wires. So I am quite sure the multimeters wires are relitively unaffected by induced voltage. Are you suggesting that no current will flow between my skin and ground when in an ac elctromagnetic field?

Comment: @SIRT: Are you sure you gave me the right impedance for the multimeter? A modern digital multimeter has an impedance of 1-10MOhm, which is closer to an electrometer than the old style 10kOhm that one would get from a galvanometer style instrument. In that case you would be detecting a capacitively coupled signal, so it's the opposite of the case that I was describing. Of course, even at 10MOhm, you are still looking at a high pass with 160Hz, so you are still not "measuring" the real change in your body's electrostatic potential. There is, of course, a current flow,  but it's small.

Comment: sorry, I don't think I made myself clear. The 10,000 ohms refers to the resistance between two points on my skin.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. So what's the impedance of the multimeter? Is the multimeter battery operated or does it have an AC power supply? The reason why I am asking is because with an AC operated instrument you are now getting into nasty problems of so called "common mode rejection".

Comment: I'm not sure of the impedance but I do know it's 9v battery operated.

Comment: OK... at this point I am not sure what to make of your description. Like I said, the current that is flowing trough your body when it acts as a capacitive antenna is quite small. A simple handheld multimeter usually won't detect it (but an electrometer will be "screaming"). I am not sure what AC signal you are seeing when you measure across your skin, unless it is induced by a magnetic field that causes a flux trough the loop made by the leads. Other signals would require a third current path, which leads to the common mode rejection problem, but that's hard to debug based on a description.

Comment: Theres no loop in the wires, I'm simply measuring the voltage difference between my skin and a ground connection. I assume the voltage difference exists due to my presence in a localised electromagnetic field. However, I'm not sure whether it's the electric or magnetic component of the field which is inducing voltage on my skin.

Comment: That would be capacitive then, i.e. you are looking at an electric field that causes a displacement current between the source and you. If your multimeter shows something, then either you are having a strong field or a pretty good multimeter. Among my current set of instruments only a professional grade voltmeter has a high enough impedance and sensitivity to register and sometimes that's more of a pain than a gain.

Comment: So would touching a ground point facilitate a flow of current? 
How would that differ from being isolated from the same point whilst in the presence of a displacement current? Is it safer to be isolated from ground?